# ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python

I am trying to install Python3 with some python libs (pyqt5, lxml) on the following machine:

```
$ uname -a    
Linux devel_server 4.11.0-22.el7a.aarch64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 3 13:39:10 CDT 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
$ cat  /etc/*-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (AltArch) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (AltArch)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (AltArch)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
SIG_FAMILY="AltArch aarch64"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (AltArch) 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (AltArch)
```

using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.5

sudo yum install openssl-devel
sudo yum install zlib-devel
cd /tmp/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz
cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}
./configure
make
sudo make install
pip3 install pyqt5
pip3 install lxml
cd -
```

everything goes well, until it gets to actually installing the python libs: `pip3 install pyqt5`.
It fails with the following output:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pyqt5
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pyqt5/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pyqt5/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyqt5/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyqt5/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

even though **open ssl is installed** (see above `sudo yum install openssl-devel`).

I tried looking through SO for an answer, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3), but the second answer (which relevant for me) suggests what I have already installed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably relevant: [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location)

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see why is it relevant...

Comment: may this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071378/how-to-make-ssl-work-in-pip3

Answer (score 0):

As of 12/23/2018 it seems latest Anaconda not compatible with Win10 Fall Update Insider's Edition yet. Had to go back to Anaconda 4.4.x to get it to work.